# Request to re-open a question which is not a duplicate

Tags: support, reopen-closed

Following advice found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question), I would like to request the re-opening of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034899/merge-using-inner-join-in-r).

Reason: it is not a duplicate as the OP was not asking how to merge 2 data frames (they knew of the `merge()` function). Rather, they were getting an error message because they were applying that function to contingency tables.

So the issue was not about how to merge data frames, but about a confusion between data frames (commonly called "tables", hence the possible confusion of the OP who may have used `as.table()` in an attempt to create such "tables"), matrices (the OP created matrices when creating the data in the first place, which might be appropriate in their workflow, but may also be due to a lack of awareness about data frames), and contingency tables.

I was just about to post an answer clarifying all this when the question got closed. I feel that it would be worth reopening it as there may be other new R users having similar confusions (and in any event, it is simply not a duplicate of the question linked to it).

### Edit

I keep getting downvotes. So I would like to add that the 2 questions look superficially very similar but if you look closely at, or run, the OP's code, you can see what their problem is. And that it is not at all about not knowing how to merge 2 data frames (which was the problem in the first question): the OP knew about the `merge()` function in this case. Rather, their problem is a confusion between data frames (commonly referred to as "tables" in common language, the very word used in the first question), and contingency tables, which have nothing to do with it and which the OP is creating with `as.table()` in a totally inappropriate context, which is the cause of this 2nd, very different issue. We call data frames "tables" but data frames are not at all created by the function `as.table()`. That function creates contingency tables. See my comments below for more details.

Also, as @Tiny Giant pointed out, the 1st question and its answers can do nothing to help the OP in this case. The OP found a solution thanks to a comment posted below their question. But this comment does not clarify the confusion and is not the best answer to the problem. I tried to answer in further comments, but this different problem deserves real answers. And not to be answered in comments because it was inappropriately closed.

So, if I may, I would like you to please have a close look at the code (ideally with some understanding of R) before jumping to the conclusion that the second question is a duplicate because it looks superficially similar.

Comment: I don't know enough about R to see why it *wouldn't* be a duplicate, but given that it was *also* closed by the OP (which is why you see the Community user in that user list), I'm not sold on the fact that the OP didn't find what they were looking for in that dupe.

Comment: The question was marked as duplicate by another user and the OP, who is obviously new to R wrongly agreed.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because the 1st question was asked by someone who understood data frames, but did not know how to merge 2 of them (they did not know about the `merge()` function), while this question is about someone who knew about the `merge()` function, but is having confusion about the very concept of data frames. They used `as.table()` because we commonly call data frames "tables", but what `as.table()` does is to coerce an object into a contingency table (so an object that has nothing to do with a data frame). So the problems (and hence the appropriate replies) are totally different

Comment: I wish I could tag this question with [r] as the reason why this is not a duplicate might not be obvious to non R users, but there is no [r] tag on Meta.

Comment: The question may *seem* very similar to the one which was linked to it (it is about merging "tables" and it even uses the same "Customer_ID" variable). And that is why a user marked it as duplicate. But if you look closely at or run the OP's code, you understand that it is not at all the same problem and there is this confusion with `as.table()` (so data frames called "tables" in common language, which is also the vocabulary used in the first question and contingency tables)

Comment: So 2 questions which superficially look very similar, but which are in fact fundamentally different if you really look at the OP's code and understand what their problem is

Comment: It definitely doesn't look like a duplicate to me, and I know nothing about r. They look like two completely different questions, and the answers at the supposed target do nothing to answer the supposed duplicate. Just because an OP clicked a button doesn't mean the question is a proper duplicate. They may have just thought that was what they were supposed to do. They may have thought the button looked shiny and just really wanted to click on it. Duplicate closure should be evaluated based on the questions, not who did the closing.

Comment: Thank you @Tiny Giant. And yes, the OP is obviously very new to R to have had such unusual confusion. And will for sure not have a very good understanding of what their problem was, or why, and why the 1st question does not help them. They got their answer from a comment posted to their question which fixes their problem but not in the best way and without explanation (which is why I think that a proper answer would be more suitable). They did not get their answer from the 1st question because, as you pointed out, it would not help them at all.

Comment: @prosoitos the easiest way to convince people that it is not duplicate is to get OP edit question to clearly explain why current duplicate is not right. Like "if that would be data frame I could use ... as shown in {link to current dup question}, but for tables that does not work. I even tried ... with the same error". While editing question also improve title and remove "thank you notes". You may try to edit yourself, but note that putting words into OP's mouth is tricky and may be frowned upon... Asking your own self-answered question that shows true MCVE may be safe route.

Comment: Thank you @AlexeiLevenkov for your advice. I am dropping the matter though. This was a very small attempt at contributing to the website, from which I have benefited myself so much before starting to become active in it recently. But I did not anticipate that it would be so difficult to make a point that is so obvious. But that is not my question and the OP got their answer from a comment. They may or may not remain confused about the difference between tables & data frames, but I got discouraged by how difficult it proved to be to provide an answer to their question. So, so be it :)

Comment: Well, I shouldn't say "so obvious" since apparently, it is not. I can't edit anymore, but I should have said "I did not anticipate that it would be so difficult to show that the dupe does *not* help fixing the OP's problem".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkoval have you read the question? It is plain as day that the questions are not duplicates. The OP just clicked the button to close their question because they "got their answer" it was just posted as a comment to the question, not as an answer to the duplicate like the button would suggest. No edits are necessary to see that the questions are in no way duplicates.

Comment: @TinyGiant I now nothing about R so I can't say if it is obvious or not... I've seen plenty of questions in my C# tags where people use completely wrong terms like "value of attribute" instead of "set local variable". I'm not sure that OP actually cared about particular way to solve they problem - seems like they tried to use "tables" for whatever they needed but ok with "data frames" solution. There very well could be solution to use "tables" directly - asking new question with better title and more searchable text would be my suggestion (can add second duplicate to original on afterwards)

Comment: @Alexei I know nothing about r, but reading the supposed duplicate and the target it is immediately clear that they are asking two very different things, and the answers to the second are of no help to the first. Duplicate reopening should be based on whether or not the two questions are duplicates or not, not whether or not the author of the question edited their question to provide a sufficient amount of meta commentary about why the question should be reopened or not. It's clear as day that they are not duplicates, and it is a disservice to leave the question closed as such.

Comment: Thank you again @TinyGiant. This is totally how I see it. This post is my very first post on Meta and it is leading me to wonder whether it makes sense to have people voting on the discussion of questions that they could not answer themselves due to a lack of knowledge of the language involved. You are a proof that knowing the language is not necessary to correctly assess duplicates, but you seem to be the exception.

Comment: If someone, however knowledgeable they are of other languages and however many badges and rep points they have, does not have the knowledge to answer a particular question, then maybe they should abstain from voting on a Meta thread regarding that question since they can easily miss aspects that have to do with the language in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with reopening that question is that it requires domain knowledge of [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), which is something of a niche technology* and few people are qualified to judge it, and even fewer of those people will stumble across that contentious closure. So the reopen process was working extremely slowly here.

Given that there have been two reopen votes already, and the amount of fierce insistence by people who I hope aren't just feigning their [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) knowledge, I have reopened the question. Please post your proper answer there now. And thanks for caring.

<sub>* don't @ me</sub>